# Passing a splat parameter from one method to another method

Tags: ruby, arrays, parameters, splat

I would like to create methods called 'add' and 'subtract' using splat parameter as below:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n }
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers[0] - add(numbers[1..-1])
end
```

But it didn't work.
What should I do to pass the splat parameter from one to another? (Especially for some specific range...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

When you call `add` function, add `*` before the array object to unpack array as multiple arguments.

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n }
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers[0] - add(*numbers[1..-1])
  #                ^
end

subtract(9, 0, 1, 2) # => 6
subtract(9, 1) # => 8
```

Comment: To make `add` function accept the only arg: `[*numbers].inject(0)…`. BTW, `[*var]` is a nice ruby trick to not care whether `var` is an array or not. Otherwise your solution will stuck on 2-elem array (`subtract(9,1)`.)

Comment: @mudasobwa, Thank you for comment. But I don't understand what do you mean stuck. `substrct(9, 1)` returns `8` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can accept numbers into the add function as an array.

```
def add(numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n }
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers[0] - add(numbers[1..-1])
end
```

A more compact way of doing this (by the way) would be

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.shift - numbers.inject(:+)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add *numbers
  [*numbers].flatten.inject 0, :+
end

def subtract *numbers
  numbers.shift - add(numbers)
end

subtract(9, 0, 1, 2) # ⇒ 6
subtract(9, 1)       # ⇒ 8
```